# Compare 7 input numbers with 7 Random Numbers

Tags: c#, numbers, console-application

I'm new in C sharp but I need help about comparing my input value and random numbers, any function, method or class I have to add..

```
List<int> lista1 = new List<int>(); 
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) 
{ 
    try { 
        Console.Write("First Number {0}: ", i); 
        int x = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()); 
        lista1.Add(x); 
    } catch (Exception ex){ 
        Console.WriteLine("The input number is incorret! It has to be whole number"); 
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message); 
        i--; 
    } 
    Console.WriteLine("Random Numbers are: "); 
    InitArray(); 
    Console.WriteLine(item); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: More like a Lottery? So you want to know if the inputted numbers match any of the random numbers? and How many are matched?

Comment: Yes I want to do that. here is my code :
List<int> lista1 = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
 {
  try
  {
Console.Write("First Number {0}: ", i);
int x = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
lista1.Add(x);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
Console.WriteLine("The input number is incorret! It has to be whole number");
Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
 i--;
 }
 }
 Console.WriteLine("Random Numbers are: ");
 InitArray();
  {
  Console.WriteLine(item);
  }

Comment: If you have more information, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56315361/edit) your question to include it. Do not try to post code in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my interpretation.

```
    class Program
{
    private static Random rnd = new Random();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
        {
            uint[] myRandoms = GetRandoms();
            uint[] userInput = GetUserInput();
            List<uint> matches = GetMatches(userInput, myRandoms);
            Console.WriteLine("Your Numbers");
            PrintEnumerable(userInput);
            Console.WriteLine("The Lottery Winners");
            PrintEnumerable(myRandoms);
            Console.WriteLine("Numbers You Matched");
            PrintEnumerable(matches);
            int NumOfMatches = matches.Count;
            if (matches.Count >= 4)
                Console.WriteLine($"You win! You matched {NumOfMatches} numbers.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, you only matched {NumOfMatches} numbers.");
            Console.WriteLine("Play again? Enter Y for yes and N for no.");
        } while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "Y");
    }
   private static uint[] GetRandoms()
    {
        uint[] newRandoms = new uint[7];
        int index = 0;
        while (index < 7)
        {
            //.Next(int, int) limits the return to a non-negative random integer 
            //that is equal to or greater than the first int and less than the second the int.
            //Said another way, it is inclusive of the first int and
            //exclusive of the second int.
            uint r = (uint)rnd.Next(1, 40);
            if (!newRandoms.Contains(r)) //prevent duplicates
            {
                newRandoms[index] = r;
                index++;
            }
        }
        return newRandoms.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    }
    private static uint[] GetUserInput()
    {
        uint[] inputs = new uint[7];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 7)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a whole number between 1 and 39 inclusive. No duplicates, please.");
            //Note: input <= 39 would cause an error if the first part of the
            // if failed and we used & instead of && (And instead of AndAlso in vb.net).
            //The second part of the if never executes if the first part fails
            //when && is used.                                                             //prevents duplicates
            if (uint.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out uint input) && input <= 39 && input >0 && !inputs.Contains(input))
            {
                inputs[i] = input;
                i++; //Note: i is not incremented unless we have a successful entry
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Try again.");
        }
        return inputs.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    }
    //I used a List<T> here because we don't know how many elements we will have.
    private static List<uint> GetMatches(uint[] input, uint[] rands)
    {
        List<uint> matches = new List<uint>();
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<7; i++)
        {
            if(rands.Contains(input[i]))
                matches.Add(input[i]);
        }
        //Or skip the for loop and do as Sunny Pelletier answered
        //matches = input.Intersect(rands).ToList();
        return matches.OrderBy(x=>x).ToList();
    }
    //You are able to send both List<T> and arrays to this method because they both implement IEnumerable
    private static void PrintEnumerable(IEnumerable<uint> ToPrint)
    {
        foreach (uint item in ToPrint)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your inputs in a list, and your random numbers in another list, your can use the following code to know the count of what is common between your lists.

```
inputs.Intersect(randoms).Count
```

Comment: I put input numbers in a list but random numbers I generate from a method I called in function.. I think I need to change my code and generate random numbers as a list..

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish that, but a simple way is to use a for loop inside of another for loop. i.e

```
int[] userInputNumbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int[] numbersToCompareTo = {1,9,11,12,4,6,16};
int countOfNumbersThatAreTheSame = 0;
for(int i=0; i<userInputNumbers.Length; i++)
{
   for(int j=0; j<numbersToCompareTo.Length; j++)
   {
       if(userInputNumbers[i] == numbersToCompareTo[j])
       {
           countOfNumbersThatAreTheSame++;
       }
   }
}

Console.Write(countOfNumbersThatAreTheSame);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Yes I want to do that. here is my code : 
List<int> lista1 = new List<int>(); for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) { try { Console.Write("First Number {0}: ", i); int x = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()); lista1.Add(x); } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("The input number is incorret! It has to be whole number"); Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message); i--; } } Console.WriteLine("Random Numbers are: "); InitArray(); { Console.WriteLine(item); }

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would Go about approaching it Cleanly using CSharp.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        public List<List<int>> Players { get; set; } //Your Players
        public List<int> RandomNumbers { get; set; } //Your Random numbers enerated my Computer
        public List<List<int>> MatchedNumbers { get; set; } //to store Matched Numbers for each player
        public int NumbersRequiredCount { get; set; } = 7; //Depends on how many numbers the players must guess, initialize to 7 numbers

        Program()
        {
            //Instantiate your objects
            Players = new List<List<int>>(); //List of Players with their list of guessed numbers
            RandomNumbers = new List<int>(); 
            MatchedNumbers = new List<List<int>>(); //To hold Matched Values
        }

        private List<int> GenerateAutoNumbers(int Count, int Min, int Max)
        {
            var Result = new List<int>(); //Result Container - will be returned
            var Random = new Random(); //Create Random Number Object
            for(int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                //Generate your random number and save
                Result.Add(Random.Next(Min, Max));
            }
            //Return "Count" Numbers of Random Numbers generated
            return Result;
        }

        public List<int> EvaluateMatches(List<int> Inputs, List<int> Bases)
        {
            var result = new List<int>();
            //Inplement a counter to check each value that was inputted
            for(int i = 0; i <  Inputs.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int r = 0; r < Bases.Count; r++)
                {
                    //Check if the current input equals the current Random Number at the given index
                    if(Inputs[i] == Bases[r])
                    {
                        //If matched. Add the matched number to the matched list
                        result.Add(Inputs[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            //At this point, all matched numbers are organized in result object
            return result; //return result object
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program App = new Program();

            //Players must input numbers - Assuming they must guess between 1 - 100
            //It can be as many players

            //Player 1
            App.Players.Add(new List<int> { 5, 47, 33, 47, 36, 89, 33 });
            //Player 2
            App.Players.Add(new List<int> { 1, 17, 38, 43, 34, 91, 24 });
            //Player 3
            App.Players.Add(new List<int> { 6, 74, 39, 58, 52, 21, 9 });

            //At this point the inputs are all in for the 3 players
            //Now generate your RandomNumbers
            App.RandomNumbers = App.GenerateAutoNumbers(App.NumbersRequiredCount, 1, 100);

            //Now you need to evaluate the guessed numbers
            //For each Player
            for(int p = 0; p < App.Players.Count; p++)
            {
                //Create the list for each user to hold the matched numbers
                App.MatchedNumbers.Add(App.EvaluateMatches(App.Players[p], App.RandomNumbers));
            }

            //Now all Players numbers are evaluated, all you need is to print the results
            Console.WriteLine("Results has been retrieved");
            Console.Write("Generated Numbers are: ");
            foreach(int i in App.RandomNumbers)
            {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Following Matches were Found: ");
            for(int p = 0; p < App.Players.Count; p++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Player {p + 1} has {App.MatchedNumbers[p].Count} Matches: ");
                foreach(int i in App.MatchedNumbers[p])
                {
                    Console.Write(i + "  ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any Key to Exit!");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

It will print the numbers matched on the screen.

Comment: I am working on that app now, I will post the code soon

Comment: I have uploaded the Code. I have tested it and it works... All you need is to change the values like your bounds 1 - 39 ... I used 1 - 100 etc. Please mark this question as answered.

Comment: I just didn't add any validations in my code. but the algorythm is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tested and working example. If you run this method *execRandomNumber();*
You will get this output ::

The numbers returned are 18
The numbers matching are 18
The numbers returned are 15
The numbers matching are 15
The numbers returned are 17
The numbers returned are 19
The numbers matching are 19
The numbers returned are 16
The numbers matching are 16
The numbers returned are 14
The numbers returned are 20
Using directives ::

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Declarations ::

```
        public static List<int> lista1 = new List<int>();
        public static List<int> returnedRandomList = new List<int>();
        public static int[] myArrNums = new[] { 12, 25, 15, 16, 18, 19 };
        public static int[] myRandArr = new[] { 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
```

Method 1 is for if you need to generate the random numbers ::

```
private void execRandomNumber()
{
    //==============Don't have the numbers but need to generate them?==============
    returnedRandomList = Gen(returnedRandomList, null);
    returnedRandomList.ForEach(delegate (int num)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("The numbers returned are ", num));
        if (numIsMatch(num) == true)
        {
            lista1.Add(num);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("The numbers matching are ", num));
        }
    });
    //==============Generator will return list of random numbers, then we compared them==============
}
```

Your number generator ::

```
    //==============Your number generator==============
    private List<int> Gen(List<int> randGenerator, Random ranNum)
    {
        ranNum = new Random();
        var rn = 0;
        returnedRandomList.Clear();
        do
        {
            if (randGenerator.Count == 7)
                    break;
            rn = ranNum.Next(14, 21);
            if (!(randGenerator.Contains(rn)) && randGenerator.Count <= 7)
                randGenerator.Add(rn);
        }
        while (randGenerator.Count <= 7);
        return randGenerator;
    }
```

And for method two, assuming you have the numbers already generated and stored in a list or array of numbers, you can do the following ::

```
private void runArgs()
{
    //==============Already have the numbers? Loop through them and compare==============
    foreach (int i in myRandArr)
    {
        if (numIsMatch(i) == true)
        {
            lista1.Add(i);
        }
    }
    lista1.ForEach(delegate (int num)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat("The numbers that match are ", num));
    });
}
```

And to compare your numbers to see if they are a match, you could do something like this ::

```
//==============Check is numbers are a match==============
private bool numIsMatch(int inValue)
{
    foreach (int ii in myArrNums)
    {
        if (ii.Equals(inValue))
            return true;
        else
            continue;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you have any questions, I will get back to you tomorrow as it is rather late here now. Hope this helps.

Comment: It has to look in console app like this:

Player 1, Enter your Number: 11 15 16 17 22 27 23
Player 2, Enter your number: 15 16 19 10 9 27 26
Player 3, Enter your number: 15 16 19 20 29 27 26
Random Numbers are: 5 6 7 16 15 27 36

Winners are:
Player 2, matched numbers: 15 16 26 27
Player 1, matched number: 15 16 27

Comment: _I'm new in C sharp but I need help about comparing my input value and random numbers,_  --




That is exactly what you asked for. My example is a perfect answer and shows you how you can do exactly that. I've provided you with a function for checking if numbers match.